# Overload functions in template classes C++

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I want to overload a function with default parameter in a template class and also i want to have a default parameter for argument
Is it possible??

Example below ::

```
template <typename T> struct endgame {
    void print<T>(T a={default value}); // some thing like this should generate different functions for different typenames

};

template <typename U> endgame<T>::print(U a) {
         cout << "Some unknow type " << a << endl;
}

template <> endgame<T>::print<int>(int a) {
cout << "Integer a " << a << endl;
}
```

THank you

Answer (score 0):

You can by specializing the template class as below:

```
template <typename T> struct endgame {
  void print(T a ={}) {
    cout << "Some unknow type " << a << endl;
  }
};

template <> struct endgame<int> {
  void print(int a ={}) {
    cout << "Integer a " << a << endl;
  }
};
```

Or if you want to specialize on the input type of `print` you could do the following:

```
template <typename T> struct endgame {
  template<typename U> void print(U a = {}) {
    cout << "Some unknow type " << a << endl;
  }
  void print(int a = {}) {
    cout << "Integer a " << a << endl;
  }
};
```